# Ionic framework: Different background color for each list-item

Tags: css, background-color, ionic-framework

I would like to have a different background color for every list-item using ionic.
For example a list of fruit containing: banana, apple, orange...
For banana the background would be yellow
For apple, it would be green
For orange, it would be yellow
...

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

I have tried to work with ng-style and ng-class but I did not succeed to obtain the wanted result.

I use collection-repeat for the list.

Thank you!

EDIT:

http://plnkr.co/edit/L80IcehgBQTiVXCCLWo9?p=preview

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js?4"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">1000 Items</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item collection-repeat="item in main.items" ng-class="item == '0' ? 'classA' ">
        {{item}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) this.items.push(i);
});
```

CSS

```
.classA { 
    background-color: black;


}
```

Comment: show us what you tried into codepen or plunkr

Comment: Hello, here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/L80IcehgBQTiVXCCLWo9?p=preview (it is the first time that I use it so I hope I did it correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ng-class` expression in error.

It should be `ng-class="item == '0' ? 'classA' : ''"`

Plus, you haven't included your **style.css** in **index.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

This is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/73riZmYm5PL41ZMBJLaI?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't work. I have placed the css file and change the ng-class expression but nothing changes. Any other idea?

Comment: Updated answer with the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/73riZmYm5PL41ZMBJLaI?p=preview).

Comment: Oups! I made a mistake modifying the plunker... It actually works sorry. Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/L80IcehgBQTiVXCCLWo9?p=preview  Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. Glad I've helped. Upvotes are always appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

CSS

```
ion-item[isOdd='true'] > div.item-content{
    background-color: yellow !important;
}

ion-item[isOdd='false'] > div.item-content{
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in main.items" isOdd="{{$odd}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to achieve alternating row or list item background color is to use AngularJS directive ng-class-even and ng-class-odd.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven